# Adding Hive SerDe jar on SparkSQL Thrift Server

Tags: json, hive, thrift, apache-spark-sql, tableau-api

I have Hive tables that point to JSON files as contents and these tables need JSON SerDe jar (from [here](https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde)) in order to query the tables. In the machine (or VM) hosting my Hadoop distro, I can simply execute in Hive or Beeline CLI:

```
ADD JAR /<local-path>/json-serde-1.0.jar;
```

and then I am able to perform SELECT queries on my Hive tables.

I need to use these Hive tables as data sources for my Tableau (installed in Windows, my host machine), so I start the Thrift server in Spark.

For Hive tables that does not contain JSON (and does not require the SerDe), Tableau can connect and read the tables easily.

When it comes to the Hive tables that contain JSON data, however, it looks like Tableau cannot find the Hive JSON SerDe jar, and I get the following error:

```
'java.lang.RuntimeException: MetaException(message:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException Class org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe not found)'.
```

How do I add the Hive JSON SerDe jar so that Tableau can read the Hive JSON tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you're using jdbc to connect tableau to hive.

When using the hive shell, hive bundles all the needed libraries (included the SerDe) from the hive client and builds a jar that is distributed and executed on the cluster. Unfortunately, the jdbc server does not do that, so you'll have to manually install and configure the SerDe on all the nodes and put it on the classpath of all the map/reduce nodes as well (copy the jar to all the nodes and add something like `HADOOP_CLASSSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:/location/of/your/serde.jar`).
It may be necessary to restart yarn as well after that.
It is quite inconvenient but that's how the jdbc driver works.

See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-5275

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm using ODBC. Particularly the Simba Spark ODBC driver from Databricks. Is the process the same for ODBC?

Comment: Yes, it should be the same procedure.